# Getting info from a Java radio button

Tags: java

I am working on some project, where a user can fill in student details in a form with textfields and radio buttons etc, and the values shall then be used to create a record in a database.

Now, this is how i started:

```
String firstName = textField_1.getText();
String surname = textField_2.getText();
String Gender = rdbtnM.getText();
```

Basically, what it does is, its retrieving values from particular input fields.
Now, my question is, for gender i have two radio buttons. rdbtnM and rdbtnF.
A user can only click on one: Male or Female.
How do i write in String Gender, that it should get the value from M or F ?

Please advise?

Comment: What does this have to do with JDBC?

Comment: Your question doesn't really have anything to do with JDBC.  This is simply getting the value of a radio button.  Where does this code live? Is it a servlet?  Is it even java?  Basically you need to get the selection of the radio button and do and if statement.

Comment: Well, I am retrieving data from textFields and other buttons, then the values will be used to create a record in the database.

Comment: @PitaSivam but your problem is in the retrieving part of that, not in the JDBC part. Mislabelling your question just reduces your chances of getting an answer. I suggest you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using Swing, with two `JRadioButton` objects inside the same group, but your question is very imprecise. If you want to do it in a simple way, you can do the following:

```
String gender // make your variable names start lower-case
if (rdbtnM.isSelected()) {
  gender = "male";
}
else if (rdbtnF.isSelected()) {
  gender = "female";
}
else {
  gender = "unknown";
}
```

You can of course avoid the last case by initializing the button states properly, but you don't provide any initialization code. There is [an official tutorial about buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton), which also explains how to deal with radio buttons by the means of ActionListeners, which I avoided here.